# Error in odata ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, odata

I have an $.ajax call in one of my html page:

```
var query = ODATA QUERY

jQuery.ajax({
     dataType: 'jsonp',
     url: query,
     jsonpCallback: 'callback',
     success: callback,
     ajaxError: alert("test"),
     timeout: 100
    });


  function callback(result) { }
```

but I have a problem, message alert appears if the query succeed but even if the query produces error. Why?

Thanks

EDIT: I try to update code with:

```
jQuery.ajax({
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      url: query,
      jsonpCallback: 'callback',
      success: callback,
      ajaxError : errore
 });

 function callback(result) { }
 function errore() {console.log("errore"); }
```

but if the query fails i get an errore in console (NetworkError: 400 Bad Request) but does not enter in the error function

Answer (score 1):

You are **calling** `alert` *immediately* and assigning its return value to `ajaxError`.

You need to assign a function there instead.

---

You then have two additional problems.

1. [`ajaxError`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/) appears to be a global event handler and not an option you can pass in the options object to `ajax`. You probably want `error` instead.
2. Both `error` and `ajaxError` say:

> This handler is not called for cross-domain script and cross-domain JSONP requests.

Comment: You can give an example?

Comment: You have an example in the code in the question. You've already done it for the success value.

Comment: is there a solution ? :(